# problem i runing react app(cross-env BROWSER=none yarn)

Tags: reactjs

I have a react app and i installed modules by npm i .it gave me no error. but when i want to start this project by npm start it gives me this error :

```
> concurrently "cross-env BROWSER=none yarn react-start" "wait-on http://localhost:3000 && electron ."

[0] events.js:377
[0]       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
[0]       ^
[0] 
[0] Error: spawn yarn ENOENT
[0]     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:277:19)
[0]     at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:472:16)
[0]     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21)
[0] Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
[0]     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:12)
[0]     at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:472:16)
[0]     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21) {
[0]   errno: -2,
[0]   code: 'ENOENT',
[0]   syscall: 'spawn yarn',
[0]   path: 'yarn',
[0]   spawnargs: [ 'react-start' ]
[0] }
[0] cross-env BROWSER=none yarn react-start exited with code 1
```

and this is scripts part :

```
"scripts": {
    "react-start": "react-scripts start",
    "react-build": "react-scripts build",
    "react-test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "react-eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "electron-build": "electron-builder",
    "release": "yarn react-build && electron-builder --publish=always",
    "build": "yarn react-build && yarn electron-build",
    "start": "concurrently \"cross-env BROWSER=none yarn react-start\" \"wait-on http://localhost:3000 && electron .\""
  },
```

what is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing  :

```
"start": "concurrently \"cross-env BROWSER=none yarn react-start\" \"wait-on http://localhost:3000 && electron .\""
```

to :

```
"start": "concurrently  \"wait-on http://localhost:3000 && electron .\" \"cross-env BROWSER=none yarn react-start\""
```

Comment: DAYS... maybe even WEEKS of searching, and your answer was the straw that broke Electrons stubborn back :) thank you so much for your input and assistance @monim!

Comment: You welcome, Happy you got my answer useful